# Science fiction romance novel with a red-haired female lead who lives in a world where dragon-esque creatures secretly coexist with humans

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

I'm looking for a science fiction romance novel i read nearly a decade ago.

This book's protagonist is a fiery red-head (I know) that has a friend who is trying to convince her to date. They live in a world where humans and dragon-esque creatures live amongst each other (I thought the term was gorgons but that must not be right. Either her boss or someone she works with is her love interest and he's very cold to her the beginning of the book.

There's a scene in the beginning where she, the male lead, and their work friends are in a club that's very dark and has a lot of stairs. He takes her home and drops her off on the balcony. He visits her often through her balcony when she's getting unwanted attention by another dragon-man until he tells her to stay at his house. They end up sleeping together and they're "mated" and then she gets kidnapped and almost sacrificed. The male lead and his brothers (also dragon-people) fly into woods and find her and save her from her kidnapper.

Does this book sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: A fiery red-head in a fantasy novel? That should be easy to find.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what was the female character's name? What age was she? Was there explicit erotic content? What did the book cover look like? How did the dragons fly? What was the setting for the book (urban, medieval, etc)? How is this 'sci-fi' (e.g. it sounds like fantasy, not science fiction)?

Comment: You've said it's Science Fiction, can you describe how? Everything you've described is stock fantasy, with no sci-fi elements whatsoever.

Comment: Sounds similar to the Heartstrikers series by Rachel Aaron, I don't remember if the female lead was red headed or not, but the dragon was locked into human form very early in the series, and the female lead had no idea he was a dragon until the end of the first book I think.